# Joining two tables with grouped elements in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

So i have the following two tables (simplified):

**Table 1: FOLDERS**

```
ID    | DESC_FOLDER | TEMPLATE_ID
---------------------------------
...   | ...         | ...
20    | Folder 1    | 52
21    | Folder 2    | 55
...   |             | ...
```

**Table 2: TEMPLATES**

```
ID    | DESC_TEMPLATE | GROUP
-----------------------------
...   | ...           | ...
51    | Template 1    | abc
52    | Template 2    | abc
53    | Template 3    | abc
54    | Template 4    | abc
55    | Template 5    | NULL
...   | ...           | ...
```

The result should be a list with all the templates and their corresponding folder.

**Expected Result:**

```
DESC_TEMPLATE | DESC_FOLDER 
---------------------------
Template 1    | Folder 1  
Template 2    | Folder 1
Template 3    | Folder 1
Template 4    | Folder 1  
Template 5    | Folder 2
```

I have problems with the grouped templates, because only one template of each group is connected to the folder. The following sql command obviously only returns the templates directly connected to the folder. How to extend my command to get the desired output?

```
Select 
    T.DESC_TEMPLATE, 
    F.DESC_FOLDER
from 
    TEMPLATES T, 
    FOLDERS F
where
    T.ID = F.TEMPLATE_ID
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Does that expected result really match the sample table data?

Comment: yep, I just double checked it :-).
Template 1-4 are grouped together ("abc"). Template 2 is connected to folder 1, so all other templates in this group are connected to folder 1 as well.

Comment: Alright, now I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a window function will solve your problem:

```
Select T.DESC_TEMPLATE, 
       MAX(F.DESC_FOLDER) OVER (PARTITION BY t.GROUP) as DESC_FOLDER
from TEMPLATES T left join
     FOLDERS F
     on T.ID = F.TEMPLATE_ID;
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm, thank you!
Now I only have to understand what you did there :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
where
    T.ID = F.TEMPLATE_ID (+)
```